# Template specialization behavior example

Tags: c++, generics, polymorphism

I am trying to understand **template specialization** in C++. I have read other forums, but cannot get it working in practice. I am trying to learn with a very simple example which I will explain.

**What I would like to accomplish:** I want foo to exhibit different behaviors based on the type. The code below does not work, but I have commented the behavior I would like to see. Could someone please fill in the lines that I commented. *Please let me know if anything is unclear.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class my_template 
{
public:
    foo() {return 0} // default behavior if there does not exist foo() function for the specified type 
};

template <>
class my_template<int> 
{
public:
    // implement foo function: should return -1 if the type = int 
};

template <>
class my_template<long>
{
public:
    // implement foo function: should return 100 if the type = long 
};

int main() 
{
    my_template<int> x;
    my_template<long> y;
    my_template<double> z;
    std::cout << x.foo() << "\n"; // print -1 
    std::cout << y.foo() << "\n"; // print 100 
    std::cout << z.foo() << "\n"; // print 0
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42 - Sorry, I didn't know the difference. I will update the title and make minor edits. My question should still be clear though.

Comment: *polymorphim* is a misspell... an 's' is missing.

Comment: `foo` inside of `my_template` shouldn't compile as you have it, either (no return type)

Comment: @Jarod42 - Is template specialization considered to be polymorphic behavior?

Answer (score 2):

**Just to show you a few different approaches.**

If you use a metafunction approach, then nothing will ever be done at run-time (guaranteed):

```
template<typename>
struct my_template{
    enum { value = 0 };
};

template<>
struct my_template<int>{
    enum { value = -1 };
};

template<>
struct my_template<long>{
    enum { value = 100 };
};

int main(){
    std::cout << "float:  " << my_template<float>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "int:    " << my_template<int>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << "long:   " << my_template<long>::value << '\n'; 
}
```

Or you could use a template variable ( C++14 ):

```
template<typename>
constexpr int my_value = 0;

template<>
constexpr int my_value<int> = -1;

template<>
constexpr int my_value<long> = 100;

int main(){
    std::cout << "float:  " << my_value<float> << '\n';
    std::cout << "int:    " << my_value<int> << '\n';
    std::cout << "long:   " << my_value<long> << '\n';
}
```

Or use a template function:

```
template<typename T> 
int func_impl(T){ return 0; }
int func_impl(int){ return -1; }
int func_impl(long){ return 100; }

template<typename T>
int func(){
    return func_impl(T(0));
}

int main(){
    std::cout << "float:  " << func<float>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "int:    " << func<int>() << '\n';
    std::cout << "long:   " << func<long>() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: your second example won't compile for me, it gives problems with constexpr

Comment: @Ryan what compiler are you using? [it works fine with gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c11b1966588d9dbe)

Comment: @Ryan microsoft is notoriously bad at keeping up with the standard.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename T>
class my_template 
{
public:
  int foo() {return 0;} // default behavior 
};

template <>
class my_template<int> 
{
public:
  int foo() {return -1;}
};
```

Is that enough?